# How to hide a message "No items found." when post widget query is empty in Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I would like to hide a message "No items found." when post widget query is empty in Elementor.

I found some cases that generate no HTML at all but in my case that message always appears when there is no post..

I am using code snippet and it would be great if I can get a right PHP code for this!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the class of the Element displaying this message and add to the style

```
{display:none;}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I would control this with PHP rather than CSS!